# How do I make these props usable to my other react files?

Tags: reactjs

```
  this.setState({
   temperature: data.main.temp,
   city: data.main,
   country: data.sys.country,
   humidity: data.main.humidity,
   description: data.weather[0].description,
   error: ""
});
```

When ever I try to call these props from another file it displays this error

### Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {temp, pressure, humidity, temp_min, temp_max}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

This is how I've been trying to call the props.

```
  <Weather
      temperature={this.state.temperature}
      city={this.state.city}
      country={this.state.country}
      humidity={this.state.humidity}
      description={this.state.description}
      error={this.state.error}
    />
```

Comment: Where's your initial state?  Something like state = { temperature: 0 } etc.

Comment: state = {
    temperature: undefined,
    city: undefined,
    country: undefined,
    humidity: undefined,
    description: undefined,
    error: undefined
  };

Comment: I'm talking about props.

Comment: Could it be you're accessing city: data.main instead of city: data.main.city or something similar?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that data.main is an object (since you reference data.main.temp). You cannot render objects. You probably meant to write:

```
city: data.main.city
```

Comment: @Nischal You are welcome. But why did my answer get -1? :-( –